# Copying and pasting data based on matched data from two workbooks (multiple criteria)

Tags: vba, excel, copy, match

I'm not that familiar with VBA, so please bear with me.

Right now, I have two excel files:

1st Workbook has the following info:

1. Unit No. (ex. EQ-21),
2. Date (ex. 05/09/2017),
3. Shift (Day Shift, Night Shift),
4. Last Name, and
5. First Name.

2nd Workbook has the following info:

1. Unit No. (ex. EQ-21),
2. Date (ex. 05/09/2017),
3. Shift (Day Shift, Night Shift),

Both of the worksheets contain one month's worth of those data (around 20,000 items), and it will need to match all three (Unit No, Date, and Shift) criteria, then copy the corresponding name from the 1st worksheet to the 2nd worksheet.

Much of what I've done was matching only based on one cell only, not with this much amount of data. Any sort of step in the right direction would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea of something that may work. (I didn't tested it)

```
Set range1 = Sheet1.Range("A1:A1500")
Set range2 = Sheet2.Range("A1:A1500")

For Each cell In range1 
    For Each cell2 In range2
         If cell = cell2 Then
             If Sheet1. Range("B"& cell.Row).value   =  Sheet2.Range("B"& cell2.Row).value   And Sheet1.Range("C"& cell.Row).value  =  Sheet2.Range("C"& cell2.Row).value   Then
                 MsgBox "ok"
                 Sheet2. Range("D"& cell2.Row).Value = Sheet1. Range("D"& cell.Row).Value
             Else
             End if 
         Else
         End if 
    Next cell
Next cell
```

EDIT :

Use this line instead of A1500 :

```
Range("A1").Select
start = ActiveCell.Row
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
end = ActiveCell.Row
Set range1 = Sheet1.Range("A1:A"&end)
Set range2 = Sheet2.Range("A1:A"&end)
```

Comment: Hello, if I'm not mistaken, a message box will appear if all criteria has been met. But what I'm looking for is once the data is matched, the name will be copied from one workbook to the other workbook. Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: I changed it to match with what you need. I guess that if you match the columns A/B/C/D with the correct data it should work.

Comment: K.Fanedoul, what if I have multiple values for every sheet I have, what can I use instead of declaring the range of up to A1500? Thanks.